# If statement in list comprehension with multiple lists

Tags: python, if-statement, zip, list-comprehension

I have two lists of equal length & want to remove values from both if their difference is less than 5:

```
X_List = [0, 95, 99, 107, 589]
Y_List = [94, 98, 104, 587, 1046]
```

I want to remove e.g. the second & third values from each using list comprehension:

```
X_list = [x if y-x <= 5 for (x,y) in zip(X_list, Y_List)]
Y_list = [y if y-x <= 5 for (x,y) in zip(X_list, Y_List)]
```

however there is an error (invalid syntax) on the 'for' part of each line. Is this due to the first y & how would I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

You've put the if in the wrong place - should be at the end; here's how to get the lists without the values:

```
x_mod = [x for x, y in zip(X_List, Y_List) if abs(x-y)>5]
Y_List = [y for x, y in zip(X_List, Y_List) if abs(x-y)>5]

X_List = x_mod
```

The first list is not directly modified, but written to a temp var. If it was, like in the original source, then the 2nd comprehension would have to work with X_List already modified, and would not produce the desired result.

I've also used absolute difference b/n the two values, as you've said the difference between the two should be more than 5, not a member of Y_List should be greater with 5.